# How to get more details on a BadRequest from HttpResponse

Tags: c#, web-services, httpresponse, error-logging

I'm trying to connect to a companies web service, but I'm getting a BadRequest value returned. I suppose that isn't a huge issue, and I'm not asking for help on how to fix the bad request. The issue I'm running into, is how to get more details on what is causing it. So I have this HttpResponseMessage Class variable:

```
HttpResponseMessage response = c.Post(address, content);
//...fill in content
response = cAssessments.Post(addressInfo, content); //return "Bad Response"
```

I send it off to their servers with the proper content, and I get back 400 response stating "Bad Request". My question is how do I dig deeper into that repsonse variable to see exactly what is causing it. I'm figuring that there is some dependance on the service I'm hitting to supply information so I'm going to assume it's in there somewhere. But what are something things inside that variable I should be looking into? For example:

"response.StatusCode" gives me the the 400 code. What other properties can I look into?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

It all depends on what the service is returning. To check that, you can read the response stream:

```
using (var stream = response.GetResponseStream ()){
    using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream, Encoding.UTF8)
    {
         var text = reader.ReadToEnd();
         // text contains your info
    }
}
```

Another useful option for debugging is using something like [postman](https://www.getpostman.com/), where you can paste in your request and see the full response immediately

If the response doesn't include any useful info, you're stuck though, there's nothing you can do about that.

Answer (score 0):

Filling content of BadRequest response with some useful tip or information what could possibly go wrong is totally up to web service which serves response. You cant do anything from your side.

Answer (score 0):

Try the Content itself, also the URL of the originating request.

Depending on the API you're requesting against, they may include what specifically caused the 400 in the response's Content.

Also the format you are requesting it in (json vs xml vs whatever)